# Determine the Coefficients in Numerical Differentiation Formula

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

Here is a question I have been thinking about for a while and I have no idea where to begin approaching it:
The following derivation formula is give:
$$
f'(x_{0})=\alpha_0f_0+\alpha_1f_1+\alpha_2f_2\quad(x_k=x_0+kh)
$$
Find $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ such that the method is
precise for $f\in P_2$. Find the error term.
My first question is: how the formula is supposed to be precise, and also an error term exists simultaneously? My second question is: What does $f\in P_2$ mean? And last but not least, I would appreciate it very much if you could provide a hint as to how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Where did the problem come from ? Can $f\in P_2$ be that $f$ is a polynomial of order 2 ?

Comment: This is a problem I was given in an exam which I could not answer, now I am curious how to solve it.

Comment: Do you know if $f_k=f(x_k)=f(x_0+kh)$ ?

Comment: No such assumption was given.